# How to get MultiList selected items in SOLR search

Tags: sitecore-client, solr

In a project, I have implemented SOLR search. I am able to get Items from search, based on template name.

In a scenario,I have to get items  using Search from a **MultiList field which are selected.**

Please provide suggestions how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use ComputedIndexField for your case.

Computed fields are a great way of storing calculated information while Sitecore indexes your items as opposed to using more resource to calculate it on the fly for use in your sublayouts/layouts.

```
public class ColorField: AbstractComputedIndexField

{  

public string FieldName { get; set; }
public string ReturnType { get; set; }

public override object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
{
  var item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

  MultilistField f = item.Fields["Colors"];

  if (f != null)
  {
     var multilist = f.GetItems();
     if (multilist == null || multilist.Length == 0)
     return null;

     return string.Join(" ", multilist.Select(t => t["Name"]));
  }

   return null;
  }

}
```

You need to register your custom computed field :

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
          <field fieldName="colorcustomfield" returnType="string">YourNamespace.ColorField,YourAssembly</field>
</fields>
```

You need to extend SearchResult item class :

```
public class  CustomSearchResultItem
{
[IndexField("colorcustomfield")]
public virtual string ColorField { get; set; }
}
```

You can use my code if you want to search for Color in a multilist field

```
 var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
   using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
   {
     var query = context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem>()
                .Where(item => item.ColorField.Contains("Red"))
                .ToList();
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Value from your multilist field in solr will look like this:

```
"multilistfield_sm":["c42546c15d30434b98bfa9f421165ea5",
  "3cf0df1b900147e88da7ab7c6fb5e236",
  "7185ea8a03474d95aacaf991917b7ed1",
  "9b5672f57f6b4e01a077e8f6deb0c3b1",
  "be945209f663495a91e75df145daff1b",
  "e815fa1cc2a34525be4208d88777c6b0",
  "28f13cabd6c041fea529ca74081c0d69"],
```

You can define your custom search result item and add your field to it, like this:

```
public class CustomSearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("multilistfield_name")]
    [DataMember]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
    public virtual IEnumerable<ID> MultilistField { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can easly query by this field or get value of this field:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var query = context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchResultItem>()
                .Where(item => item.MultilistField.Contains(someId))
                .ToList();
}
```